# Then sum of digits in $M\times N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $\bf{M = \underbrace{777777777777777777777}_{99-times}}$ and $\bf{N = \underbrace{999999999999999999999}_{77-times}},$ Then sum of digits in  $M\times N$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write $$M = 7(1+10+10^2+\cdots \cdots +10^{98}) = \frac{7}{9}(10^{99}-1)$$

and write $$N = 9(1+10+10^2+\cdots \cdots +10^{76}) = \frac{9}{9}(10^{77}-1) = (10^{77}-1)$$

So $$M\times N = \frac{7}{9}(10^{99}-1)\times (10^{77}-1)=\frac{7}{9}\left[10^{196}-10^{77}-10^{99}+1\right]$$

Now how can i solve it after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: The question is not clear... "Then sum of digit in the product of $M \times N$". Check it please.

Comment: Why not try some smaller ones that you can do on a calculator, $777\times9$, $77777\times99$, and suchlike, and look for patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $N=10^{77}-1$, hence $MN=$

$\underbrace{7\dots7}_{99}\cdot(10^{77}-1)=$

$\underbrace{7\dots7}_{99}\cdot10^{77}-\underbrace{7\dots7}_{99}=$

$\underbrace{7\dots7}_{99}\underbrace{0\dots0}_{77}-\underbrace{7\dots7}_{99}=$

$\underbrace{7\dots7}_{76}6\underbrace{9\dots9}_{22}\underbrace{2\dots2}_{76}3$

Hence the digit-sum of $MN$ is $7\cdot76+6+9\cdot22+2\cdot76+3=891$.